# Rims for Camera Buttons

Tags: modifiers, topology

right now I try to create little holes which are formed like these menu buttons so there is a little space between the body of the camera and the buttons. Unfortunately the Boolean doesn't work properly and creates no hole. Is there another way to solve this problem beside the boolean?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The *Knife project* tool could be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The Knife Project tool is an alternative to the boolean. You must constrain the 3D View to an orthographic camera angle in order to get it to work. Think of it as using a light beam which is aligned to your current viewing angle, which then casts a shadow of one object onto another object, to create cuts at all the points of intersection between the two objects. You could use an open-ended cylinder (must be open-ended, or else the projection will be blocked) to create a series of edges defining the button hole. Then you could simply select the all the faces contained within the newly created edges -- as they now form a circle on the surface of the camera -- and extrude them, delete them, or otherwise edit them as needed.

Steps:

Start by making sure you're in Object Mode. Select the cylinder first, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + select the camera body to include it in the selection.

[image]

Then, with both selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit Mode (both objects will remain selected in Edit Mode, which is important). Press whichever numpad key corresponds to the viewing angle that would be perpendicular to your camera's main surface (this is likely to be the *Front* view, which is accessed by <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, though Front may actually not be the correct view in your case. You'll have to check). Once the correct view is attained, look to the top of the 3D View for the *Mesh* Menu. Under it, you'll find **Knife Project**.

[image]

Once this option is chosen, you're done, but it won't look like anything happened. Go back to Object Mode to hide or delete the cylinder. It still won't look like anything happened. Go into Edit Mode, and you will see the new edges made by the cylinder on the surface of the camera body. Edit as needed.